# Accessing NiFi bulletins using Rest API

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to access NiFi Bulletins using Rest API so that I can take some actions based in the bulletins instead of just displaying them on the NiFi Canvas. I have searched a couple of options including using the bulletin info on host machine but not working for me that well. If any one has a prior experience implement it, can you please share?

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is available in NiPyApi, a NiFi API Python Client SDK:

```
# In Bash
$> pip install nipyapi
$> python
# In Python
>>> import nipyapi
>>> nipyapi.nifi.FlowApi().get_bulletins()
{'bulletins': [],
 'controller_service_bulletins': [],
 'reporting_task_bulletins': []}
>>> nipyapi.nifi.FlowApi().get_bulletin_board()
{'bulletin_board': {'bulletins': [], 'generated': '12:36:24 UTC'}}
>>> my_processor = nipyapi.canvas.get_processor('nipyapi_console')
>>> my_processor.bulletins
[]
```

I will add some convenience methods for this in the next release, thanks for the idea!

Edit: I have added the following convenience methods to NiPyApi, they will be in release 0.8.0 shortly:

```
nipyapi.canvas.get_bulletins
nipyapi.canvas.get_bulletin_board
```